# Find $\int f(x) dx$ by simple calculus

Tags: calculus

$\int^{2x^2}_{0}f(t/2)dt = e^{-1/x^2}-e^{-1/2}$.

Then what is $\int f(x) dx$?

I tried to let $s=t/2$, plug in, get $2\int^{2x^2}_{0}f(s)ds=e^{-1/x^2}-e^{-1/2}$. Then let $x=\sqrt{y/2}$, we have $\int_0^yf(s)ds=(e^{-2/y}-e^{-1/2})/2$. So $\int f(x) dx = e^{-2/x}/2+C$.

But the solution given in my answer book is $e^{-1/x}/2+C$. Anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: hint: use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Be very careful mixing dummy variables and free parameters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2}-\mathrm{e}^{-1/2}=\int_0^{2x^2} f(t/2)\,dt=2\int_0^{x^2} f(u)\,du
$$
and hence
$$
\int_0^{x} f(u)\,du=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-1/x}-\mathrm{e}^{-1/2}\right)
$$

Comment: Why $2x^2$ is changed to $x^2$ after you use $u=t/2$?

Comment: Got it: $t=2x^2$, so $u=t/2=x^2$. Thanks.